# Definition generalized logics and stationary logics

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Can someone explain or give a definition of what is "generalized logics" and what is "stationary logics"? From the text where these terms appeared I know, that generalized logics is not first order logic.

Comment: What text? Some context would be appreciated. In any case, try the "Model theoretic logics" book.

Comment: this text:Menachem Magidor: Inner models constructed by using generalized logics (ongoing work):
"I shall survey some recent developments in an ongoing project (jointly with J. Kennedy and J. Väänänen) in which we study inner models which are constructed similarly to L, but where we replace first order logic by some generalized logic. The issues we shall consider are basic properties and absoluteness of the models. Special role will be played by the model we get by using stationary logic." ... I have no more context... it is the description of a speech he is going to give

Comment: Are these his lecture notes from Barcelona last year or something like that?

Comment: no, well I don't know if these are his lecture notes from Barcelona, ... but he's just going give this speech in a week or so in Münster

Comment: Oh. He's going to talk about this topic? Hmm. Nice.

Comment: Yes, indeed he is.

Comment: Well. I would suggest to try and find Menachem and Jouko's notes from their mini-course last year in Barcelona. It was a very good course aimed for grad students, so it covered all the basics. I don't recall exactly, but I think you'd be more interested in Jouko's lectures in this case.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot

Comment: Apparently there's a booklet, http://www.crm.cat/en/Activities/Curs_2016-2017/Documents/Notes.pdf

Comment: So, did you follow the lecture?

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal definition of a generalized logic (as far as I'm aware) but the informal description is to start with first order logic and add to it by allowing

- infinite sequences of quantifiers,
- infinite disjunctions and conjunction or
- special predicates - typically interpreted in $V$ - our true background universe.

A particularly nice example of a generalized logic is $\mathcal L(aa)$ - the stationary logic. $\mathcal L(aa)$ is just first order logic with an additional second order quantifier $\operatorname{aa}$. We have, for any given model $\mathcal L(aa)$-model $\mathcal M$
$$
\mathcal M \models \operatorname{aa}s \phi(s) : \iff \{ A \in [M]^{\le \omega} \mid \mathcal M \models \phi(A) \} \text{ contains a club (in } V \text{).}
$$

The meaning of this additional quantifier becomes more apparent in specific examples. Say that $\phi$ is a $2$-ary formula in the language of set theory and $\mathcal M$ is an $\mathcal{L}(\operatorname{aa})$-model such that
$$
\phi(\mathcal{M}) := \{ (x,y) \mid x,y \in \mathcal{M} \wedge \mathcal{M} \models \phi(x,y) \}
$$
is (in $V$) a linear order. Then we can express the statement "$\phi(\mathcal M)$ has confinality $\le \omega$" in $\mathcal{L}(\operatorname{aa})$ as follows:
$$
\mathcal M \models \operatorname{aa} s \forall x \exists y (\phi(x,y) \wedge s(y) ).
$$
We can even express the fact that $\mathcal M$ itself is at most countable as
$$
\mathcal{M} \models \operatorname{aa}s \forall x (s(x)).
$$
Both examples demonstrate that $\mathcal{L}(\operatorname{aa})$ has strictly stronger expressible power than first order logic. And still $\mathcal{L}(\operatorname{aa})$ satisfies many desirable model theoretic properties. It satisfies a version of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, countable compactness, has a nice proof theory, ...

You can find all of this and much more in

- [Barwise, Kaufmann. Stationary Logic](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484378900037) and
- [Kennedy, Magidor, Väänänen. Inner Models from Extended Logics](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni16006.pdf).